# CNAME for github repository already taken, but earlier repo was deleted?

Tags: web, github, dns, github-pages, cname

About two years ago, I created a repository to host a website via Github Pages with a custom domain. As time went on, I wanted to discontinue that project so I deleted that repository. I am currently trying to relaunch that website. However, whenever I go to the Settings part of my repository and down to the Github Pages section and try to enter my custom domain, I get the following warning:

[image: Warning Image]
Does anyone know how I can fix this solution? There is no other repo on Github that uses this CNAME and I own this domain. When I go to the URL it just says that there's a `404 There isn't a GitHub Pages site here.` from Github. Any help would be appreciated and in the mean time I am trying to contact Github Support.

EDIT: If it's any additional help, I have included the Advanced DNS info from NameCheap:

[image: Advanced DNS Info]